# Can I change the port or host of the Developer Portal?

Tags: apiconnect

Is it possible to change the port the Developer Portal uses? It's default is set to 443. Can we also change the actual URL?

Comment: Are you using the self installed version or the saas version on Bluemix?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is No

Given that Portal does not support changing the url in any reverse proxy then it is very likely you would want to expose the portal on anything other than 443. If you are wanting to use a dodgy port then its likely you are intending to modify the URL in some kind of reverse proxy - you need to make sure you know that is explicitly not allowed and will not work.